# Is It Safe to Remove Local Service Accounts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have changed my SQL Server services to use domain service account. The server still has `NT Service\MSSQL$INSTANCENAME` and `NT Service\SQLAgent$INSTANCENAME` listed under `Security\Logins`. They each have the sysadmin role granted to them. Since they are not used by the services, can I safely remove them from the Logins on the server? I have search a bit online but haven't found a good answer to this question. I just want to make sure these accounts aren't used for anything else.

Comment: Why don't you just remove them from the `sysadmin` role? Also it can be a double-edged sword because [you may need certain service accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49677/no-sa-password-no-sql-server-management-studio-no-os-authentication/49680#49680) to regain access to your server if you lose the SA password or the domain account gets removed.

Comment: Removing them from the 'sysadmin' role would be acceptable. I just want to make sure that there's nothing I'm missing outside of that. You make a good point for leaving the accounts there.