Does a system protected password automatically get included in SSMS when it is downloaded?
I work at a company where most things are password protected by a system admin password (which I dont have). Today I downloaded SQL Server and set up a basic local server. I was able to get in but when I went to create a new database it told me I didnt have authority.
I went to the security --> login tab and saw that it had not automatically defaulted my account to system administrator. Looking at the SA account, I can see it is password protected. Despite my best efforts I am unable to grant myself sysadmin access.
Does anyone know if SQL Server would automatically include the system password? I put no passwords in when setting up the server.
Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated.

During the installation, which authentication mode did you select? (The choices are "Windows Authentication Mode" and "Mixed Mode".)

start the instance in single user mode, add your windows account as sysadmin. https://www.sqlshack.com/recover-lost-sa-password/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/how-do-you-reset-the-sa-password or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out

"I went to the security --> login tab and saw that it had not automatically defaulted my account to system administrator." - Yes, that's to be expected. It doesn't automatically do that. You have to specify which accounts you want to be in the SysAdmin role during installation. Which accounts you can specify during installation will depend on which authentication mode you selected, as mentioned by Doug.

Whilst running the installer there is a button you can click to add the account of the installing admin as a windows auth user (shown in the screenshot in this Q https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/112011/3690) - I presume you didn't do this?
