# Is this true? `Members of the local computer administrator group can always elevate their privileges to sysadmin.`

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/determining-effective-database-engine-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15#summary

Is this true that `Members of the local computer administrator group can always elevate their privileges to sysadmin.`

I am confused because the local administrator group is not automatically added to the sql security post 2008. And so they cannot login into the SQL server instance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a user with Local Administrator level access can do literally anything they want to the system.

Take a look at this [question-and-answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/how-to-add-new-sysadmin-account-when-no-sysadmin-accounts-exist) that explains how to add a user to the sysadmin SQL Server role when no current sysadmin is available.

Comment: Does this only work when "single user mode"?

Comment: Yes. The ability to login as a Windows administrator now being sysadmin in SQL Server even if your windows account doesn't exist in SQL Server requires starting SQL Server in single user mode.

Comment: @Tibor - take a look at the link I edited into the answer above which shows how to do that without starting SQL Server in single user mode.  I thought it was quite interesting.  Also, I wouldn't recommend taking that approach on a production system, but nonetheless it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You have to bear in mind that a user with local administrator rights can literally do anything they want, including for example, attaching a debugger to `sqlservr.exe` process and modifying code or memory directly. They could also take ownership of the `master` database file and modify it with a hex editor.

**You cannot lock them out**, because there are many ways for them to elevate to `SYSTEM` rights, at which point they can do anything they want anyway.

For example, one of the methods on [the excellent post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/how-to-add-new-sysadmin-account-when-no-sysadmin-accounts-exist) linked by @StephenMorris uses impersonation. An administrator can impersonate any user, so they could act as the `MSSQLSERVER` user.

Answer (score 1):

> am confused because the local administrator group is not automatically added to the sql security post 2008. And so they cannot login into the SQL server instance.

Adding to the correct *technical* answers, the Windows Admin *owns* the server.  And so while we don't want Windows Admins connecting to the SQL instance as a privileged user (or at all) by default, the Windows Admin must always be able to "take ownership" of the instance and the data.

By analogy a home may have locks on bedroom or bathroom doors, but these aren't intended to permanently deny access to the homeowner.  Only to prevent accidental or casual access.