# Cannot Login to Fresh Installation of SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, logins

I just deployed a fresh installation of SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server 2012 Datacenter R2 environment. The installation completed with 0 warnings and 0 failures.

During the installation I specified Integrated Windows Authentication so it did not prompt me for a local SA password. I added the domain security group that should be granted administrative rights as well.

Immediately after the installer completed, I launched SMSS and am greeted by this error when attempting to connect.

[image]

After clicking okay and then pressing "Connect" a second time I get this dialog.

[image]

The TechNet article relating to this issue says to ensure that Named Pipes is behind TCP/IP in the protocol order, which it is.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I tried switching to SQL Authentication mode by launching in Single User Mode, enabling the 'sa' account and setting the password but the errors remain the same.

Comment: Open the ERRORLOG file with notepad (you'll have to search your system for ERRORLOG files with no extension) and see what *state* is associated with the 18456 error. You can see a mapping here. https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: Possibly stupid questions but have you double checked that you created a default instance not a named one?  Are you certain that the service is actually running?

Comment: @Kenneth it looks from the Configuration Manager screen shot that it is a default instance. We can't tell from there whether it's actually running, but the Login failed error means it must be.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Duh, I missed the Network Config entry.  And your right of course.  If he get's a login error it has to be up.

Comment: Also, when you installed SQL Server, did you add this login to the list of the instance's administrators? This is an extra step not covered by merely selecting Windows Auth during setup (though it is on the same screen).

Comment: Aaron, yes. There is an AD group that was specified as being instance administrators and the account I'm attempting to login with belongs to that group as well as Domain Admins

Comment: Well, seeing the state will help, but it might have been better to specify an explicit user as well, rather than just an AD group.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49767/1186

Comment: I'm finding that out as I dig deeper. It didn't throw an error at all but I am about to go in and run EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember
'domain\username', 'sysadmin'; GO to see if that helps

Answer (score 3):

Yup, that last little comment was it. Even though you can select a domain group for the Instance administrators, it will create this problem. You must add individual user accounts. Thanks for the help and pointers!

In the end I put it into single user mode and ran the following command from an elevated prompt:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost from the command prompt

EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember
'domain\username', 'sysadmin'; GO

exit
```

Restarted the SQL services normally and went right in.